# Excel function to make SQL-like queries on worksheet data?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, function

I have a largish table in an Excel worksheet:

```
Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3

ValueA       ValueB     ValueC
....
```

What I need is a function that will take as input the range and an SQL-like query String and return a range of rows that match the query, e.g.:

```
=SQL_SELECT(A1:C1000, "SELECT * WHERE Column_1 = ValueH AND Column_3 = blah")
```

Does something like this exist? Or what would be the best way to implement myself?

Comment: If you can save the worksheet then you have the option to use ADO and Jet/ACE to treat the workbook as a database, and execute SQL against the sheet.

Comment: [pivot tables](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[excel]+pivot+table&submit=search)?

Comment: Stumbled across this due to a recent "late answer". Surprised no-one seems to have mentioned Excel's "Advanced Filter" functionality, which is at least in the right ball-park here.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `Get External Data` (despite its name), located in the 'Data' tab of Excel 2010, to set up a `connection` in a workbook to query data from itself.  Use `From Other Sources` `From Microsoft Query` to connect to Excel

Once set up you can use `VBA` to manipulate the `connection` to, among other thing, view and modify the SQL command that drives the query.  This query *does* reference the in memory workbook, so doesn't require a save to refresh the latest data.

Here's a quick `Sub` to demonstrate accessing the connection objects

```vb
Sub DemoConnection()
    Dim c As Connections
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set c = wb.Connections
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        ' Reresh the data
        c(i).Refresh 
        ' view the SQL query
        strSQL = c(i).ODBCConnection.CommandText
        MsgBox strSQL
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, looks to be just what I am looking for

Comment: could you tick that this answered your question Richard?

Comment: I get an "object doesn't support this action" error at the strSQL = c(i).odbcconnection.commandtext line

Comment: @JustinJDavies - these days i am behind a corporate firewall so SO access irregular. Now accepted.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Richard! Sounds like a sorry state of affairs if you are fire-walled from such a useful resource.

Comment: Hi, guys! Is there a way to get it to auto-refresh the data returned, making it dynamic? (Just like the "QUERY" function in Google Spreadsheet). I kow I could use VBA to do that - just want to know if I can get it working without VBA.

Comment: how do you perform this on a mac? Microsoft query is not showing up

Answer (score 5):

If you can save the workbook then you have the option to use ADO and Jet/ACE to treat the workbook as a database, and execute SQL against the sheet.

The MSDN information on how to hit Excel using ADO can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819).

Comment: Hmm that is certainly a possibility, thanks for the suggestion but would prefer not to have to reference "externally" as I would essentially be doing here

Comment: What do you mean by "externally"?

Comment: well ADO/Jet references a shreadsheet on the filesystem (which also means the sheet needs to be saved) as opposed to the in-memory range.

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to do this is to create a column with a formula that evaluates to true for the rows you care about and then filter for the value TRUE in that column.

Answer (score 2):

If you want run formula on worksheet by function that execute SQL statement then use Add-in A-Tools

Example, `function BS_SQL("SELECT ...")`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes SUM_IF can get the job done.

Suppose you have a sheet of product information, including unique `productID` in column A and unit price in column P. And a sheet of purchase order entries with product IDs in column A, and you want column T to calculate the unit price for the entry.

The following formula will do the trick in cell Entries!T2 and can be copied to the other cells in the same column.

```
=SUMIF(Products!$A$2:$A$9999,Entries!$A2, Products!$P$2:$9999)
```

Then you could have another column with number of items per entry and multiply it with the unit price to get total cost for the entry.