# How can I write a database like query in excel using just functions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have some data that's structured in a table like this:

[image: existing table].

I have another tab on my spreadsheet where I eliminate any duplicate category entries and want to concatenate the data to look like this:

[image: new table]

I need to create this **using a function** and **not a macro or Visual Basic**.  I've already written the function to eliminate any of the duplicate category entries and now I need to figure out how to take each of those unique categories and append the data behind it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Edited to embed the images. This way, if the images are taken off Picasa, the question doesn't become obsolete.

Comment: I believe what would need is to write ***MACRO***

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel function to make SQL-like queries on worksheet data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756802/excel-function-to-make-sql-like-queries-on-worksheet-data)

Comment: @chrisneilsen I don't think so; while the poster refers to 'a database like query', what they are after is really formatting, not lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first image comes from `Sheet1` and the second `Sheet2`, here's a way to do it. You need to add at least one calculated column to `Sheet1` and optionally two calculated rows to `Sheet2`.

1. Uniquely identify each row on `Sheet1`. Add a new column `A` with the formula `=B3&COUNTIF($B$3:B3,B3)` in `A3` and fill down. You'll have `first1` in `A3`, `first2` in `A4` and so on.
2. Identify each block of columns on `Sheet2`. Add a new row `6` with the formula `=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)` in `B6` and fill across. The values will be `1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3`. You can type these in manually if you like but it won't scale as easily.
3. Work out the column of each data item in `Sheet1` and put in the columns for `Sheet2`. Add a new row `7` to `Sheet2` with the formula `=MATCH(B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$E$2,0)` and fill across. The values will be `3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5`. We now know, for each cell in `Sheet2`, which instance of the category we have and in which column the data variable comes from.
4. Use `VLOOKUP` to find `first1` and return data column `3` within the data table. On `Sheet2`, set cell `B3` to `=VLOOKUP($A3&B$6,Sheet1!$A$2:$E$8,B$7,FALSE)` and fill down and across.
5. You'll have a number of `#N/A` errors (e.g. cell `E4`). If you have a newer version of Excel, you can use `IFERROR()` to escape this; otherwise, use `=IF(ISNULL(<formula>), "", <formula>)` where `<formula>` is the formula in step 4.

To summarise:

- Create a unique, sequential, calculable row ID for each row in the source.
- Determine which instance of that sequence is used by each column in the destination. This is appended to the end of the category to determine the row IDs formed in the previous step.
- Determine which column contains the data for each column in the destination.
- Look up the row with the calculated row ID and find the relevant column for this data item.
- Format the results appropriately.