# Sum of max in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Please do not mark this as duplicated of [Sum of Max in PivotTable for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563086/sum-of-max-in-pivottable-for-excel) because there is no even answer for it.

I have a pivot table of items grouped by ID and month, and getting the maximum Q among all items. So the totals get the maximums as well.

```
    +------------+---------+----------------+
    |    A       |    B    |       C        |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |1|  Month     |  ID     |  Max(Q)        |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |2|  1         |  A      |  23            |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |3|  1         |  B      |  11            |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |4| Subtotal 1 |                      23  |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |5|  2         |  C      |  85            |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |6|  2         |  D      |  6             |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |7| Subtotal 2 |                      85  |
  +-+------------+--------------------------+
  |8|  Total                            85  |
  +-+---------------------------------------+
```

What I want to do is still get the max of each ID, but the totals to be the sum of the maximums. Like the following.

```
    +------------+---------+----------------+
    |    A       |    B    |       C        |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |1|  Month     |  ID     |  Sum(Max(Q))   |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |2|  1         |  A      |  23            |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |3|  1         |  B      |  11            |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |4| Subtotal 1 |                      34  |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |5|  2         |  C      |  85            |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |6|  2         |  D      |  6             |
  +-+------------+---------+----------------+
  |7| Subtotal 2 |                      91  |
  +-+------------+--------------------------+
  |8|  Total                           125  |
  +-+---------------------------------------+
```

I can't do the trick of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URfAkq0_dj0 because:

1. I can't alter the DB.
2. The origin table is in the data model so I think it's the reason why I'm not able to select a custom subtotal (Not sure, correct me if I'm wrong).

[image: Custom subtotal]

Any ideas?

Oh, also I'm open to use VBA.

Comment: Just a side note - you can't choose a question as duplicate unless it has an upvoted or accepted answer, so the one you linked isn't applicable. Can you include a screenshot of your actual pivot table and how it's setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in pivot. But if you can add helper column to source table, you can use following array formula to calculate `MAX` value in group and then use this column in pivot:

```
{=IF(SUM((A2=$A$2:$A2)*(B2=$B$2:$B2))=1;MAX((A2=$A$2:$A$15)*(B2=$B$2:$B$15)*($C$2:$C$15));0)}
```

Change semicolons to commas if needed.

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your pivottable looks something like this:

[image: img1]

You can right click the subtotal line, go to "Summarize Values By" and select "Sum":

[image: img2]

Which results in:

[image: img3]

Comment: This would work if I had only one item per ID, where the sum and the max are the same value. The thing is I must find the max item per ID -setting the summary to Max- then sum the maxes on each month.

Comment: @Javier Have you tried messing around with the running totals?

Comment: I almost got it showing values as running total in ID. The last ID actually showed the sum of all maxes, but next I need to link the result to another cell. Because of the changing input, the last ID is never the same to `GETPIVOTDATA` it, and it is never placed in the same cell to directly reference it.

Comment: Probably the solution is a formula in the destination cell.

Comment: Actually my solution was to keep the pivot table showing maxes, then use a `VLOOKUP` in destination cells to get the respective sums.