# execute sql query on excel columns using vba

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm doing excel data verification and would like to view any discrepancies within each column. And I think executing

```
"select distinct column1 from table_name"
```

is efficient.
Is there a way to do that in vba with/without connecting to any database?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8766541/445425) may be of some use

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the SELECT DISTINCT for one column:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A65536").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("B2"), Unique:=True
```

The code will paste the Distinct values from activesheet column A to column B. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps. But I don't want to change the raw file anyway :)

Comment: If you need something more specific let me know.. I answered according to question ;)

Comment: Okay. I want the queried results as a recordset or something and handle the results in vba. So is creating an object connection the only option?

Comment: you could loop for every cell in the column.. if the count of cell value is 1 in the column add it to an array