# Use excel workbook like a function

Tags: python, excel, function, vba

I found this on a related subject - [Excel function to make SQL-like queries on worksheet data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756802/excel-function-to-make-sql-like-queries-on-worksheet-data)

But I was wondering **if there is any way to use an excel workbook/file like a function in a separate workbook/file**? 
So I have an excel workbook that has a control page - where I can input parameters *1,2,3*. And based on those parameter, the outpage page will display the correlating data. I know I can duplictae the output page to show the outputs for all three parameters and link these to my other workbook.

However, is there any way to (in the other excel file) do something like `FILENAME_otherfile.function(1).range(A1)` or something? to extract the cell *A1* with parameter 1 as an input? 
And in the same file also call `FILENAME_otherfile.function(2).range(A1)`?

Comment: Actually, is there any way to use an excel sheet as a function in the same way within the same workbook?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "as a function" ... you just want to acces values?

Comment: yes, but the way the data file is made, instead of having an output page for parameters 1,2,3, it has one output table where it displays the outputs for a given parameter (1,2,3) that is put into a cell. so what I want to do is be able to insert a line in a file saying: 1)insert value of cell C1 given the parameter input as 1 2) while also in another part of the work book insert a line saying "insert value of C1 given the parameter is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very inelegant way of doing it, but we can keep the interface as pretty as possible.

1. Open the workbook with a `Application.Workbooks.Open()`
2. Set its attribute to `Hidden` for aesthetic reasons.
3. Say you want to manipulate cells on *"Sheet1"* then Set `InputRange` and `OutputRange` (cells where you'll see the outputs) to the appropriate ranges in the opened workbook.
4. Change `InputRange.Cells(m,n).Value`
5. Get into some variable what happens, for e.g.

   ```
   Dim MyAnswer as Double 
   MyAnswer =  OutputRange.Cells(x,y)
   ```
6. Close the workbook, preferably not saving it (as your programming logic requires) and use the `MyAnswer` value as your *'function'* output.

Comment: Actually I get this now - but this won't make it so the value is dynamic right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. Do you wish to change a value in a spreadsheet and use the other spreadsheet as a function and see the answer back in your sheet? If so, you'll need to open FunctionWorkbook, modify the input-cell in it so it's replaced by a formula "=MyDisplaySheetInputCellReference" and then add a reference to FunctionWorkbook in your DisplaySheet. IMHO, not worth it. It's far more efficient to re-encode it, or at worst, do it via a macro... and to make it dynamic, maybe you can trap a Worksheet_Change() event so your macro runs whenever the input cells change.

Comment: Hi, was the answer posted above useful? If so, please accept and vote on it. Thanks