# SQL function in Excel

Tags: sql, excel

How can I use an SQL function that gives me a table in Excel. I looked everywhere and couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756802/excel-function-to-make-sql-like-queries-on-worksheet-data

Answer (score 0):

you will need  programming to perform this task.
 many programming languages support such features.