# Count row with multiple values in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet contain 600 thousand row, I want to select one column.

for example please see the attachment picture

Here in the column there are multiple values, I want to count it and the result must be for example

number of value 1 it's = 55

number of the value 8 it's = 23

seems this to do it's easy but I have 600 thousand with multiple values.

[image]

Comment: You are looking to do a basic database operation and for this reason I would recommend using pivot tables.  You should be able to take care of this in a few minutes: http://www.contextures.com/pivottablecountunique.html#pivot

Comment: Alternatively (to the pivot table solution) you can also use Microsoft's Query Editor to query your Excel file (internally) on another sheet with something like `SELECT Column1, COUNT(1) from [$Sheet1]`. Look here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8766541/1153513

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how many times you have to change the column and what you have to do with the informations you get.

Without this info the best solution is the following:

1. select the column you have to analyze;
2. push Insert;
3. hit Pivot table
4. select Pivot Table.

Now you have only one field that you can put inside ROWS and inside VALUES (select COUNT).
This will give you an unique list of the elements and the amount of each one.